# JAXBContext, jaxb.properties and moxy

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

The `jaxb.properties` needs to be in the ***same package as the domain classes*** you are creating the JAXBContext on.

I am using Moxy's xml driven configuration since I doesn't want to use annotations or XJC generated objects. I have an existing domain classes that are spread across multiple packages. Does this mean that i need to have the `jaxb.properties` present in all those packages or there is a better alternative (Maybe writing my own implementation of some interface that can read from a jvm arg or something)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does this mean that i need to have the jaxb.properties present in all
>   those packages?

If you are creating your `JAXBContext` on classes, then you need to have a `jaxb.properties` file in at least one of the packages of the domain classes passed in.  In the example below you could have a `jaxb.properties` file in either `package1` or `package2`.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(package1.Foo.class, package2.Bar.class);
```

If you are creating your `JAXBContext` on package names, then you need to have a `jaxb.properties` files in at least one of the packages.  Note that packages are separated by a ':'.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("package1:package2");
```

---

> or there is a better alternative

My preference is to use the standard JAXB APIs with a `jaxb.properties` file to specify MOXy as the JAXB provider.  Some people prefer using the native MOXy APIs to do this:

```
JAXBContext jc = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {Foo.class, Bar.class}, null);
```

---

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: In the link provided, I see the below as ouput if I specify the jaxb.properties in only 1 package. "class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl". As you can see, the package in which the jaxb.props is not there, it is reverting back to the suns implementation. Are we not going to have issues with this?

Comment: As long as the `jaxb.properties` file is in one of the packages of the classes passed to create the `JAXBContext` you are ok.  That is what I tried to demonstrate with that post.  Are you seeing different results when running that example?

Comment: I haven't yet run that example but reading your post raised this doubt to me as you didn't bring a closure on that. It would be good if you can update your post to explicitly state that "This behavior is OK".

Comment: @Pangea - I have updated the post in an attempt to make this more clear.  Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: I cannot put a .properties file in my java folders. I think this is also against the WTP 2.0 default setup of classpath and folders. Am I missing something? The moxy configuration seems quite chaotic.

Comment: I am trying to use the alternative mentioned here. That is helping to use Moxy without the properties file. But getting this exception "Invalid XPath for XMLDirectMapping/XMLCompositeDirectCollectionMapping. XPath must either contain an @ symbol for attributes or end in /text() for text nodes. For example: "@name" or "name/text()". Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: @Aparna - Do you know what property it is complaining about, it's type, and what annotation is on it?

Comment: @Blaise : Got my error. I was missing the text(). That corrected it. Thanks!