# JAXB/MOXy - Unmarshall values of child and nested children in a single class including support for element with the same name

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling, moxy

I'd like to unmarshall a xml file with nested children with same name to a single class. I tried everything I found but nothing work, the values of nested children remain null.

What is wrong ?

jaxb.properties

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

myFile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clock>
  <name>myClock</name>
  <times>
    <starttime>09:00</starttime>
    <endtime>12:00</endtime>
    <starttime>13:00</starttime>
    <endtime>17:00</endtime>
  </times>
</clock>
```

Clock.java

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Clock {

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @XmlPath("times/starttime[1]/text()")
    private String amStartTime;

    @XmlPath("times/endtime[1]/text()")
    private String amEndTime;

    @XmlPath("times/starttime[2]/text()")
    private String pmStartTime;

    @XmlPath("times/endtime[2]/text()")
    private String pmEndTime;

}
```

Test code

```
File file = new File("myFile.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Clock.class);

Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Clock clock = (Clock) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(clock, System.out);
```

Ouput

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<clock>
    <name>myClock</name>
</clock>
```

Comment: What do you get if you fully populate your object model and marshal it?  Also if you call `.getClass()` on your `jaxbContext` what do you see as the real class?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`
`<clock>`
`    <name>myClock</name>`
`    <amStartTime>1:00</amStartTime>`
`    <amEndTime>2:00</amEndTime>`
`    <pmStartTime>3:00</pmStartTime>`
`    <pmEndTime>4:00</pmEndTime>`
`</clock>`

and

`class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl`

Comment: I finally found where was my mistake. My jaxb.properties was not read because it wasn't in the package of my domain class. Now it works perfectly !

Comment: Can you add that as an answer?  This will help people in the future who encounter this in the future and find your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 solutions found here : [JAXBContext, jaxb.properties and moxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785543/jaxbcontext-jaxb-properties-and-moxy)

I can either put the jaxb.properties in the package of Clock.java or get my JABXContext instance this way :

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {Clock.class}, null);
```